# H264 stream to Janus using ffmpeg on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, streaming

I'm trying to live stream the Raspberry Pi camera feed using rtp to a Janus gateway running on the same Raspberry Pi. The Janus and the demo pages are working so far, e.g. the streaming page streams both sample audios to a browser on a different computer.

What I need is a working ffmpeg one-liner to take the camera at /dev/video0 as input and output an rtp stream to Janus, maybe also with a corresponding `/opt/janus/etc/janus/janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg`

What I've found so far is a working one-liner using raspivid piped into gstreamer but that laggs hard:

> raspivid --verbose --nopreview -hf -vf --width 640 --height 480 --framerate 30 --bitrate 1000000 --profile baseline --timeout 0 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=126 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004

I'm looking for something similar to this (which apparently is not working/playing on the demo page):

> ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -codec:v h264 -i /dev/video0 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s 640x480 -b:v 1000k -f rtp rtp://localhost:8004

My `/opt/janus/etc/janus/janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg` looks like this (tried with and without commenting out the single line):

```
h264-sample: {
    type = "rtp"
    id = 10
    description = "H.264 live stream"
    audio = false
    video = true
    videoport = 8004
    videopt = 96
    videortpmap = "H264/90000"
    #videofmtp = "profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1"
    videofmtp = "packetization-mode=1"
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a lot of research and trial/error I've finally found a solution using gstreamer. You can use something like this which plays perfectly fine via Janus while also being able to **adjust the resolution, bitrate and the port** of the stream:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004`

To embed the **current time and date** (in this case the format is 14:55:03 01.08.2019) directly in the stream, you can use:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! clockoverlay time-format="%H:%M:%S %d.%m.%Y" outline-color=-16777216 color=-1 draw-shadow=false font-desc="myriad pro bold expanded 16" ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004`

For a **nightly live stream** (using IR Leds) I use the following one which is **brighter but has less contrast** (e.g. it's almost black and white) as you can't see colors anyway. Also you can stream to **two different ports simultaneously**:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src extra-controls="c,brightness=65,saturation=-60" device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! clockoverlay time-format="%H:%M:%S %d.%m.%Y" outline-color=-16777216 color=-1 draw-shadow=false font-desc="myriad pro bold expanded 16" ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=3000000 control-rate=variable ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink clients=127.0.0.1:8004,127.0.0.1:8040`

To **save a stream using the matroska container** (e.g. after a movement detection/timer) you can use this:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=8040 ! application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=livecamera2.mp4`

And to **stream the same file**:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=livecamera2.mp4 ! matroskademux ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004`

I hope this will be helpful for someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I could use `ffmpeg` to stream my webcam video like this.

```
$ ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 8192 -input_format yuyv422 \
    -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 10 -i /dev/video0 \
    -c:v h264_omx -profile:v baseline -b:v 1M -bf 0 \
    -flags:v +global_header -bsf:v "dump_extra=freq=keyframe" \
    -max_delay 0 -an -bufsize 1M -vsync 1 -g 10 \
    -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:8004/
```

There may be more better ffmpeg option settings though.